# How to get the element in an array?(python)

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
array =[[[1, 0.25], [1, 0.19], [1, 0.19]], [[1, 0.89], [0, 0.93], [0, 0.48], [1, 0.49], [0, 0.6], [0, 0.6], [1, 0.34]]]
```

This array consists of two arrays. I want to get these two. How could I do? 
The result should something like this:

```
sub1=[[1, 0.25], [1, 0.19], [1, 0.19]]
sub2=[[1, 0.89], [0, 0.93], [0, 0.48], [1, 0.49], [0, 0.6], [0, 0.6], [1, 0.34]]
```

The code is:

```
for i in array:
    print array[i]
```

Then I got:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop gives the elements in the array not the indices of those elements so you should have:

```
for item in array:
    print(item)
```

or to be more similar to what you have written:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
     print(array[i])
```

although the first is considered more "Pythonic".